# How to stop an input image field from losing its value on update in php?

Tags: php, wordpress, file, input

I have what I believe to be a simple problem, however, I am stumped. I am working on a list of custom fields for a custom type in Wordpress for a plugin. I want to have a dynamic amount of custom fields depending on another post being linked (that's probably a complicated way of stating the issue).

It seems to work fine with the input types that I have on the page, however for the input file type, which is read only, everytime that I click to update the values that were stored previously are lost. I understand why this happens, when the page loads after saving a value the  has no value. I show the image in a  tag. When I add a different image to a different custom field, the original image now sends no data to the php script. Therefore the original value is lost.

Here is the relevant php:

```
// Attribute Images...
$save_img_values = array();
foreach ($_FILES['paired_att_img']['name'] as $key => $att_img) {
    $file_name = $_FILES['paired_att_img']['name'][$key];
    $file_tmp = $_FILES['paired_att_img']['tmp_name'][$key];
    $upload = wp_upload_bits($file_name, null, file_get_contents($file_tmp));
    if (isset($upload['error']) && $upload['error'] != false) {
        continue;
    } else {
        $save_img_values[$key] = $upload['url'];
    } 
}
update_post_meta($post->ID, 'paired_atts_img', $save_img_values);
```

Please no comments on the hideous code, It needs refactoring, but I want to get it working first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in actual fact I found the answer! Feel free to let me know why this wouldn't be a good idea if it isn't but essentially I just added this in:

```
$custom_imgs = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'paired_atts_img', false);
if (count($custom_imgs) > 0)
    $custom_img = $custom_imgs[0];
else
    $custom_img = array();
$save_img_values = $custom_img;
```

and then the rest as before. So in essence we retrieve the values on the save rather than on the load. Maybe too much time in asp.net stopped me from seeing something so obvious.